# Архитектура в AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, mvc

Скажите пожалуйста можно ли создавать  для каждого контроллера сервис который будет в себе хронить логику контроллера к которому относиться. И может ли такой сервис содержать не реюзабельными методы(методы которые будут исп. только в одном контроллере).
  Если выше указанное являеться недопустимым то как правильно строить "Архитектуру" - по данной проблеме.
  Гуглил пишут "бизнес логику в серисы"- что подразумевается под этим термином.?

Comment: Можно пару примеров, того в чём у вас затруднения7

Comment: "бизнес логику в сервисы" - это именно то, что вы и описали. Вся логика должна быть в сервисах. В контроллерах только переменные, необходимые для работы со `view`. Контроллеры должны быть максимально тонкими, т.е. как можно меньше содержать логики. То что в сервисах будут не переиспользуемые методы - ничего страшного.